# How to decipher the Google Flights results' URL?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, google-flights

I am trying to get the cheapest flights to multiple destinations using **Google Flights**.

I use the following code for one destination but I need to loop through multiple airports:

```python
from selenium import webdriver
url = 'https://www.google.com/flights?hl=de#flt=/m/03hrz.BOM.2020-10-14;c:EUR;e:1;so:1;sd:1;t:f;tt:o'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.gws-flights-results__cheapest-price').text)
#print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.gws-flights-results__cheapest-price').text)
driver.quit()
```

Now, I just have to understand how **Google Flights** changes the universal airport codes.
For example "HAM", in to their own code e.g. "03hrz".
By knowing these conversion rules I can use it for multiple airports and find out the prices for multiple destinations.

Could somebody please help me out here?